# Kubernetes service account with upgrade/patch permission to annotation of deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-rbac

I want to create kubernetes service account and roles/rbac which will grant permission to patch/update annotations of deployment. service account should not able to perform any other update on kubernetes deployment. It should have upgrade and patch permission on metadata section only.

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example on how you can create your service account depending your needs, you can take my example and easily modify, it looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role # it can be ClusterRole if you want your service account for all nodes and across all namespaces
metadata:
  namespace: default # if can specify any your working namespace
  name: depl-patch-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group, you can set any specific group
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["update", "patch"]

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: depl-patch-sa

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: depl-patch-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: depl-patch-sa
  apiGroup: "" # same as above
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: depl-patch-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

Hope this helps. You can find more info about roles/rbac in [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples)

Comment: nope.this will give permission to patch anything. What i want is to allow patch of specifc section.

Comment: @AkshayGopani, there is no such built-in possibility, feel free to create a python script to do so